Express routing does not recognize :id parameter
app.get('api/v1/tours/:id', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  const id = req.params.id * 1;
  const tour = tours.find((el) => el.id === id);
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Success',
    results: 1,
    data: {
      tour,
    },
  });
});

The code above is how I handle the get request of the API I'm coding (following a tutorial) and for some reason the :id parameter is not recognized.
So when I try to make a get request to localhost:3000/api/v1/tours/5 it will look for the URL that ends with 5 instead of reading it as a parameter.
And the handler above never gets triggered as nothing gets logged on the console.
SOLUTION:
the leading slash was missing so instead of using: 'api/v1/tours/:id' , the correct syntax is '/api/v1/tours/:id'

Add leading slash i.e. '/api/v1/tours/:id'

It worked! Thank you so much!

welcome you are

@EcryAMV Don't add the answer inside the question. Add it as an answer, then mark your own answer as the solution. Alternatively, ask the commenter to add their comment as an answer, then accept it.

…the correct syntax is '/api/v1/tours/:id'. But that is exactly the same syntax.
